# Why Azure IoT Hub has Event Hub as an endpoint?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

I am new to Azure and I found out that Azure provides option to route messages from IoT Hub to Event Hub (Event Hub as an endpoint).

My question is in which use case one would route the data from IoT Hub to Event Hub ? I was going through one of the document provided by Microsoft which shows feature comparison of the different services provided by Azure IoT Hub compared to Event Hub (see the picture attached). It comes out that even the basic Tier of IoT Hub has more features than the Event Hub. then why exactly one would route his data to Event Hub ?

[IoT Hub vs Event Hub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dVia.png)

I got this image from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-compare-event-hubs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably a broad answer , but here is an example of where we used in the past.

This depends on use cases one may have. In the past , examples we have used this pattern were when we had to write specific route based filter for specific sets of messages (say from different classes of edge devices) or based on message priority. May be there are use cases where you want to enable EventHub capture to save specific classes of messages to blobs which you want to be separate from the device message stream or similar.

Technically one could dequeue the messages off an IoT hub and then route these messages as well , but then it is a lot more easier to route messages based on headers into different "routes" , than pick up messages in batch introspect and then route them

Comment: There is "Message Routing" which has filter option within it which could route the message based on some header or some classes, for this we need to pass the required query and the messages are routed based on the query pattern matching.